# How To Resize The Widths Of Menu Items in UberMenu

Tags: plugins, menu

I installed the Ubermenu plugin on my site here:

[aep.gov.tr](http://www.aep.gov.tr)

The widths of the menu items are too wide. Therefore the menu does not fit into its container as shown here:

[image]

How can I make the width of the menu items narrower?

Comment: What is "ubermenu"? Btw: Why have you got a turkish goverment domain?

Comment: Ubermenu is a plugin that improves the menu. It has great features. http://codecanyon.net/item/ubermenu-wordpress-mega-menu-plugin/154703?ref=sevenspark

The web site is for a government agency.

Comment: As it's migrated it doesn't matter anymore for this question, but for further questions: Closed source plugins or paid plugins are out of scope for WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a CSS question / issue than related to Wordpress. Your main problem is this right here on line 36 of your style.css:

```
.navigation ul li a{display:block; float:left; color:#666; text-decoration:none; padding:15px 0 0 0; height:28px; width:130px;}
```

You need to remove the width property of your `<li>` tag here. This will bring your menu up on one line.

So what you will have is this instead:

```
.navigation ul li a{display:block; float:left; color:#666; text-decoration:none; padding:15px 0 0 0; height:28px;}
```

I would suggest playing around with your width properties and your height properties to force the menu to look right. Another suggestion is to use Firebug for Firefox or for Google Chrome to help debug CSS issues. It helps you find them fast.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **admin.css** file and note that you may loose your warranty, change the following:

```
#megaMenu.megaFullWidth
{
    width:100%;
}
```

to

```
#megaMenu.megaFullWidth
{
    width:auto;
}
```

Hope it will help.